# Optimize an SQL query to display 0s for empty data

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table that has this data:

[image: Sample data]

I have this query:

```
select count(id) "Count",
       case id
           when 0 then 'Zeroes'
           when 1 then 'Ones'
       end "Name",
       sum(num1) "Num 1",
       sum(num2) "Num 2",
       sum(num3) "Num 3"
from mytable
where added_date >= :FROM_DT
and added_date <= :TO_DT
group by id;
```

When :FROM_DT is 01-JAN-2018 and :TO_DT is 02-JAN-2018 I get the following result:
[image: Sample output]

However, when I change :TO_DT to 01-JAN-2018 I get the following result:
[image: Sample output]

I want it to show a second row with zeroes for Zeroes.

I have this query that I'm not sure is optimized or not:

```
select "Count",
       "Name",
       NVL("Num 1", 0) "Num 1",
       NVL("Num 2", 0) "Num 2",
       NVL("Num 3", 0) "Num 3"
from (
    select count(id) "Count",
        'Ones' "Name",
        sum(num1) "Num 1",
        sum(num2) "Num 2",
        sum(num3) "Num 3"
    from mytable
    where added_date >= :FROM_DT
    and added_date <= :TO_DT
    and id = 1
    union
    select count(id) "Count",
           'Zeroes' "Name",
            sum(num1) "Num 1",
            sum(num2) "Num 2",
            sum(num3) "Num 3"
    from mytable
    where added_date >= :FROM_DT
    and added_date <= :TO_DT
    and id = 0
)
```

The results I get from this query is what I want:

[image: Sample Result Wanted]

I'm using this query on a lot of data so I want to know if there's a way to get the results I want with a faster query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a `left join` would be more appropriate.  If you can list the values:

```
select count(t.id) as "Count",
       i.Name,
       coalesce(sum(t.num1), 0) as num_1,
       coalesce(sum(t.num2), 0) as num_2,
       coalesce(sum(t.num3), 0) as num_3
from (select 0, 'Zeroes' from dual
      union all 
      select 1, 'Ones' from dual
     ) i left join
     mytable t
     on i.id = t.id and
        t.added_date >= :FROM_DT and
        t.added_date <= :TO_DT
group by i.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select sum(case when id >0 then 1 else 0 end ) "Count",
   case id
       when 0 then 'Zeroes'
       when 1 then 'Ones'
   end "Name",
   sum(case when id >0 then num1 else 0 end ) "Num 1",
   sum(case when id >0 then num2 else 0 end ) "Num 2",
   sum(case when id >0 then num3 else 0 end ) "Num 3"
from mytable
where added_date >= '20180101'
and added_date <= '20180102'
group by id;
```